# Probably 101 stuff but... how do I replace characters like % and " using a Word Macro

Tags: vba, replace

HI Sorry to bother people with I'm sure a very basic problem. i'm a journalist and i need to change words like percent into % and " into ' as I pull stories off the website and put it into my magazine. I could try to get the in-house people to help me but it would take a ticket, and six months then, nothing would happen. I've worked out how to do a lot of the replacements/removals using basic Word macro like this:

```
.Text = "€"""
        .Replacement.Text = "^+"
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Text = "<sup>"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
```

but It falls over when I try to replace "%" or """. 
I think it must be because % and " are special symbols.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, % and " are both recognised characters and must be "escaped". Use a backslash to escape special symbols like this:

\" or \%